# Azure storage and security

Tags: azure, azure-storage

For a new web application that is going to be built in Azure we are thinking of storing sensitive personal documents (scans of passports, educational transcripts, etc) in Azure blob.

Is this a secure enough approach or is there a better way of doing this? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you read the security guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide ? Does that sounds enough for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage service encryption is enabled by default for all storage accounts. You have the option to use your own encryption keys if you wish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption

If you wish to create custom keys managed by Azure Key Vault, you can follow instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption-customer-managed-keys

However, if you worry about the data as it is being transferred to Azure blob, you will need to use client-side encryption as well. Here is the link for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-client-side-encryption?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fqueues%2ftoc.json

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (which is kinda unanswerable anyway, given the open-ended "is it secure enough?") - Also, encryption or not, this doesn't address public vs private blobs, virtual network vs public access, CORS, http vs https, etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree but the scope of this question is huge...so I sensed from question that encryption is the concern and blob is not public... that said, this could've been a comment...

Answer (score 2):

Like many things in Azure, it can be secure, but takes effort to do so.

1) As of last year, all storage accounts are encrypted at rest using Microsoft-managed keys using AES-256.  You can also bring your own key, as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-service-encryption-customer-managed-keys).

2) Employ client side encryption - that way, if the account was compromised, the attacker can't read the data; they also need the key to decrypt the data.  This does influence performance, but is often acceptable for most scenarios.

3) Use the storage account's firewall to permit only the addresses that require access to the storage account.

Side note: If you're accessing Storage from an App Service, the outbound IP addresses **will not change** unless you scale the App Service Plan up or down.  Auto-scaling your app service horizontally does not change the outbound IP addresses.

4) Integrate the storage account with Azure KeyVault to automatically rotate the keys and generate SAS tokens, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys).  I wish this could be done via the portal, as most people aren't aware that this exists.

5) Do not use the storage account keys - generate and hand out short lived SAS tokens. KeyVault integration can help with this.

6) Enable storage diagnostics metrics and logging. While not a defensive measure by itself, it can be helpful after the fact.

7) Enable soft delete; this may reduce the impact of certain attacks if a breach were to occur.

8) Enable the 'secure transfer required' setting, to permit traffic only over HTTPS.